# Intent putExtra from PagerAdapter to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments

I need to get the vales passed from `ThePagerAdapter.java` inside `SliderHome.java`. How can I implement this? I have tried a lot, but no success.

This is my code:

**ThePagerAdapter.java**

```
public class ThePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
Context context;

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}

public ThePagerAdapter(Context context,List<Slider> list) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, int position) {
    // Declare Variables
    ImageView imgflag;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_item, container, false);

    // Capture position and set to the TextViews
    final String id =  list.get(position).getId();

    imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    imgflag.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i = new Intent(context, SliderMore.class);
            i.putExtra("slider_id", id);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

}
}
```

From the above `PagerAdapter` I am send values to another `Fragment` described below using `Intent.putExtra`

**SliderHome.java**

```
public class SliderHome extends Fragment {

ViewPager viewPager;
ImageView iv2,iv3;
String slider_id;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slider_more, container, false);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    iv2 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    iv3 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

    return rootView;
}
```

Is there a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As an example, read the first example of fragments by google itself: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: @Blackbelt : yes, I want to get `i.putExtra("slider_id", id);` values in `SliderMore`

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal : how to make it possible?

Comment: It is not possible start a fragment using startActivity(intent), read the google guide fragments, to pass params to fragment probably you will use fragment.setArguments(bundle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this cases I like to use a Factory Method Pattern.

Example:

```
public static MatchDetailSummaryFragment newInstance(String matchIdString, int position) {
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARGS_MY_ID, matchIdString);
    args.putInt(ARG_POSITION,position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public MyFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.mPosition = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);
    this.id = getArguments().getString(ARGS_MY_ID) != null)
}
```

You can invoke this:

```
public void fillMyPagerAdapter()
{

    mChildFragments = new Hashtable<Integer,GxuBaseFragment>();
    int count = 0;

        MyFragment a = MyFragment.newInstance(Integer.toString(my.getId()),count);
        mChildFragments.put(count,a);
        count += 1;

    mViewPagerAdapter.setTabHolderScrollingContent(this);
    mPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);
    mPagerSlidingTabStrip.setViewPager(mPager);
    mPagerSlidingTabStrip.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

}
```

This code may not work because is a couple of extracts of my production code but it will explain the main ideas.